# Erro ao copiar arquivos entre servidores

Tags: ubuntu, servidor

Estou copiando arquivos via rsync entre dois servidores linux, o comando que estou utilizando é:

```
rsync -Cravzpt --remove-source-files --exclude 'script.sh' --exclude 'index.php' /var/www/html/bkpserver/tarefario root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/html/
```

Mas quando executo esse comando, ele pede senha do root e após alguns segundos, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] 
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Eu não faço a mínima ideia do por que está tendo esse erro, pois tenho exatamente o mesmo comando em mais 3 servidores diferentes e copiando para o mesmo servidor de destino e todos funcionam.

Comment: Essa pergunta não é sobre programação. Deve ter outra comunidade do SO que lá com isso.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi  A pergunta não é de programação.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Dei o enter antes da hora, A pergutna não é especificamente de programação mas é sobre servidores ubuntu. Acho que está no escopo.

Comment: Existe o Server fault Stack Exchange

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Então me diga, que tipo de pergunta pode ser feito nessas tags que ele assinalou? Ubuntu e Servidor. Ora, Ora. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não estava conseguindo me conectar ao servidor de destino pois o servidor de origem não tinha uma chave RSA. Segui o tutorial "Gerando as chaves SSH e automatizando o acesso" que é encontrado no link:
[Backups remotos com rSync e chaves SSH](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Backups-remotos-com-rSync-e-chaves-SSH) e o backup começou a funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro diz que o servidor recusou a conexao, pode ser um firewall bloqueando, um roteador no meio da conexao ou a porta 22 do ssh fechada. Tente o seguinte (exemplos aqui pressupõe o debian ou ubuntu):

1) Veja se o serviço ssh esta ativo

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status
[sudo] senha para sidon: 
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Qui 2017-07-20 08:27:25 BRT; 4h 36min ago
  Process: 1896 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1145 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 1.4M
      CPU: 23ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1145 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Observe a linha `Active: active (running)...`

2) Se estiver rodando, verifique em que porta:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Port
Port 22
```

3) Veja se a porta esta aberta:

```
sudo netstat -pln | grep '22'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*           OUÇA   1145/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22               :::*                OUÇA   1145/sshd
```

Faça isso no lado servidor que não está aceitando a conexão.

Se tudo isso estiver ok (SSH ativo na porta 22 aberta, sem firewall bloqueando) veja se o servidor esta conectado a um roteador, nesse caso o roteador funciona como, digamos... um intermediário ou mesmo um "firewall", então voce precisa fazer um redirecionamento NAT, ou seja qdo o comando rsync requisita a porta 22, a requisição "bate" no roteador e ele não sabe o que fazer, então vc tem redirecionar a 22 para o ip do servidor.

Comment: Olá, @Sidon, desculpe não lhe dar um retorno antes. Efetuei os testes que você passou nessa resposta, os 3 itens estão ok. Ambos os servidores (o de origem e o de destino) estão hospedados na DigitalOcean e não tem nenhuma configuração de Firewall além das padrões da própria D.O.

Comment: Consegui fazer o rsync rodar via comando direto no putty, mas pela tarefa cron continua o mesmo problema.